# Convert CSV to Excel table

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, xlsx

I'm trying to convert a CSV file to xls.

The CSV file looks like this:

```
410E   54B9    C700    0   0   0   0
```

but when the convert is done the result is

```
410E;54B9;C700;0;0;0;0
```

```
Const xlDelimited                =  1
Const xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote =  1
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook          = 51

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xl.Workbooks.OpenText "C:\sssss.csv", , , xlDelimited _
  , xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, True, True, True, True, True, True, _
  , Array(Array(1,2), Array(2,2), Array(3,2), Array(4,1), Array(5,2) _
  , Array(6,1), Array(7,1), Array(8,1), Array(9,1), Array(10,1), Array(11,1))
Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook

wb.SaveAs "C:ssss.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook, , , , False
wb.Close

xl.Quit
```

I want it as a table.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is very particular about what it accepts as CSV. Rename the file to something other than .csv (e.g. `C:\sssss.txt`) and the code should work as you expect. Otherwise you need to change the content of the file (substitute the semicolons with commas) to match Excel's expectations.

Comment: but I want convert from .csv to xls and not from txt to xls.

Comment: @user3657176 Changing the extension doesn't change anything about the content of the file.

Comment: i know, but I will  do it from csv to excel without change csv to txt and then convert it.

Comment: I told you what you need to do. If you ignore the advice you were given you're on your own. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a lot more arguments than you need, this should do the job:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\ssss.csv", _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
```

Having said that, if you are using a different type of space character in your CSV than the normal space character you may need to use this:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\ssss.csv", _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:=" "
```

Copy and paste the space character from the CSV to between the double quotes after OtherChar.

But also, as Ansgar said, if the file extension is .csv, then Excel ignores all of those rules and just opens the file as a CSV.

You can rename the file with `Name`, or you can continue to open the file and add a text to columns function straight after the import:

```
Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:=";"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That comment is about as helpful as a reply that is 8 months late. Why isn't it working? What is the problem? What part isn't working?